# Django JSONField, how can i get the count of occurences for values stored in a list

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Database is postgres 9.4
In my table i'm using a JSONField

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()
```

Example data JSONField of 3 records:

```
{"color": ["yellow", "blue", "red"], "size": ["S", "L"], "material": "cotton"}

{"color": ["white", "blue", "gray"], "size": ["XL", "L"], "material": "cotton"}

{"color": ["yellow", "gray", "red"], "size": ["L", "XL"], "material": "cotton"}
```

My goal is to create a list which contains the count of each occuring color and size:

color:
yellow 2
blue 2
red 2
gray 2
white 1

size:
L 3
XL 2
S 1

**Is this possible ? What would be the best solution in terms of performance.**

So far i managed te produce a list containing all occuring lists with:

```
Item.objects.values_list('data__color').distinct().annotate(num=Count('data_color'))
```

color:

```
["yellow", "blue", "red"], 1

["white", "blue", "gray"], 1

["yellow", "gray", "red"], 1
```

Comment: What if you use the `__len` lookup? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#len

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't very good support to perform such complex queries on JSON fields using ORM in Django. Doing this completely using ORM will not be straight forward. It's better to use raw sql query here.  In terms of SQL query, you can use

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(colors::jsonb) as color_count, count(*)
FROM (SELECT meta ->> 'color' as colors
      FROM core_dummymodel) AS tbl
GROUP BY color_count;
```

to get the colors count and a similar query for sizes.

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(sizes::jsonb) as sizes_count, count(*)
from (SELECT meta ->> 'size' as sizes
      FROM core_dummymodel) AS tbl
GROUP BY color_count;
```

Here is the outcome for colors:

[image]

Comment: In pure SQL it works but with Django's raw() manager it gives an error: 'Raw query must include the primary key'

Comment: How are you doing the query? Can you paste it here in the comment?

Comment: `query = "SELECT jsonb_array_elements(color::jsonb) as color_count, count(*)
                FROM(SELECT jsdata ->> 'color' as color
                FROM wb_item WHERE price > 0)  AS tbl GROUP BY color_count  ;"
qs = Item.objects.raw(query)`

Comment: Just include `1 as id,` in you select statement and it will work. So change your query to `query = "SELECT 1 as id, jsonb_array_elements(color::jsonb) as color_count, count(*) FROM(SELECT jsdata ->> 'color' as color FROM wb_item WHERE price > 0) AS tbl GROUP BY color_count ;"`

Comment: Still can't get this to work. Using the connection.cursor() to get my data from the data is definitely the way to go for the more complex queries. Thanks again.